# Container will not position correctly

Tags: html, css

As you can see the container ( box with text and animation ), is positioned fine, the second container is positioned underneath, I am wanting it positioned vertically right. Please help me get it there!

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/zwm26j9a/][1]
```

sorry for the mass amount of css.
I have tried changing the css for several hours!

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwm26j9a/

Comment: do you want this two block in same line ?

Comment: yeah, basically the second box  to be to the right of the first one (in line with each other)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are using old bootstrap , you need to change first row `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 feature-column">` to `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 feature-column">` now you colum is bigger then you need to change child divs `vc_col-sm-4` to `vc_col-sm-3` , because your `.vc_col-sm-4` have `100% width` , may be that have done by you , change this your issue will be fixed

Comment: please check this answer, and the current situation, bootstrap have `col-lg- , col-md , col-sm , col-xs- ` for devices and desktop ,  and if you have'nt this class use media queries

Comment: if the answer is working for you , dont forget to tick the answer

Comment: @JishnuVS, hi jishnu, can u contact me logeshrsr@gmail.com please.

Answer (score 0):

change your css here:

```
body .vc_row-fluid .vc_col-sm-4 {
   width: 48%; // instead of width 100%
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: that made each box really small but inline

Comment: @digitalhive this might be a bad idea

Comment: please help me lmao @JishnuVS

Comment: @digitalhive, it (box) cant be made inline if u not shortern the box width.

Comment: this is the result I get

Comment: @digitalhive if u want each box inline, u have to reduce the box width like Taniya did.

Comment: but reducing the box width makes the boxes extremely small, resulting in a ot of blank area and very little room for text etc.

Comment: so if window size strches. you don't have a problem with that

Comment: then if i want more containers It addes underneath again @Logeshwaran

Comment: so you want all your containers horizontal and you can scroll horizontal to see them. does that sums it

Comment: @digitalhive  https://gyazo.com/a42aec120325e6f36cdb5b6d79b4006e is this is what u need?